# ImportError: No module named 'flask.ext'

Tags: python, flask, python-import, importerror

When I import a Flask extension like this, it works fine:

```
from flask_module import Module
```

So the extension is installed correctly.

But whenever I try to import a Flask extension like this:

```
from flask.ext.module import Module
```

I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'flask.ext'`

What is going wrong here?

I'm not sure if this information is useful but anyway:

1. I haven't found extensions that do work in the last way
2. I use Windows 10, Python3.5 and Flask 1.0.2
3. I'm in a virtual envirionment

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because the question marked as duplicate was about a different error being raised. Of course I did look for my error but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why some guy marked that "duplicate" but not show the link or solution

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The "flask.ext" style of naming/importing modules has been [deprecated since 2016](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/1484). [Here's the reasoning](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1135#issuecomment-61860862). You should use the first style you described instead:

```py
# Use this import format
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

As for the suggestion that you install your flask packages globally, this somewhat defeats the purpose of using a venv in the first place. It makes it impossible to use `pip freeze --local > requirements.txt` to only save relevant packages, opening you up to package version conflicts.

Comment: I wish that docs were updated

Comment: e.g. from flask_session import Session (docs are still outdated)

Comment: Docs still not updated as of August 2022

Comment: If you see a `flask.ext` import in documentation for a Flask extension, that's a red flag that the code is abandonware. It's been deprecated for 6 years now. The Flask docs no longer mention it, beyond the deprecation warnings in the Changelog.