# Virtual Env not recognising the Flask file in python script

Tags: python, html, macos, flask, python-venv

I am trying to find out why Virtual Env on my Mac won't recognise any of the Flask Libraries when I try to run my Python Script.

I have uninstalled and installed the flask and tried to upgrade it all. But for some reason i keep getting the same error.

I have attached my code and error.

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Length

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'top secret!'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)


class NameForm(Form):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[Required(),
                                                         Length(1, 16)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the error i receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.ext'
```

Would appreciate all assistance!

Comment: after activating your env, did you `python -m pip install flask`?

Comment: yes. But still doesn't work. Even uninstalled and re-installed from there, but to no avail.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55024677/13891412) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261872/13891412) answer your question?